# Processing hex-arrays which have got some information encoded

Tags: python-3.x, hex

I'm not sure if the name is misleading, so bear with me, please.
So, basically I get hex arrays with even number of elements that look like this:

> DD120134A1A2B3E588

Average `len()` is about 200.
Every two symbols aka 'bytes' have got some information associated with them, for example, `DD` is a preamble which translates as a packet starting element.
The next block `12` is a software version
The next block `0134` is a query number.
The next block `A1` is a query type field which has three possible values (A1 - accepted, A2 - denied, A3 - undefined)
Etc.

What I need to do is to 'decode' such a packet into a text table with all the blocks with their corresponding meanings:

```
DD>>>>Packet preamble
12>>>>Version: 18
0134>>Query number: 13313
A1>>>>Query type: accepted
```

> What have you tried to do so far?

Basically, I created around 5 dictionaries with field values as keys. Now, what I don't like about my code is that it basically consists of tonnes of `if`s and `elif`s, which seems like a dirty code. Also, since some fields haven't got an associated meaning per se, but rather should be just converted into an `int` value, I ended up having a dictionary with a 'byte' index number as a key value, i.e. `1: preamble` etc, which just feels wrong.

What is a conceptually appropriate way of dealing with such a task? How do you call such a task? Is it parsing or something else?
Thanks!

Comment: Is the format of the data always the same?  By that I mean there is no variability in the length of any field.  If this is the case, you could probably define a class with properties for each field and then partition out the different fields by referencing the different properties.

Comment: Have you looked at the [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) library for devising a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there might be a better approach here is my suggestion
class datastruct:
def **init**(self, data_in):
self.wrd = data_in
@property
def preamble(self):
msk = 0xFF0000000000000000
offst = 0x10000000000000000
if (self.wrd & msk)//offst == 0xdd:
return 'Packet Preamble'
else:
return 'Bad Packet'

```
@property
def version(self):
    msk = 0x00FF00000000000000
    offst = 0x100000000000000
    return f'Version: {(self.wrd & msk)//offst}'

@property
def queryNo(self):
    msk =  0x0000FFFF0000000000
    offst = 0x1000000000 
    return f'Query No: {hex((self.wrd & msk)//offst)}'

@property
def queryType(self):
    qryTypes = {'0xa1':'accepted', '0xa2':'denied','0xa3':'undefined'}
    msk = 0x00000000FF00000000
    offst = 0x100000000 
    qt = hex((self.wrd&msk)//offst)
    return f'Query type {qryTypes[str(qt)]}'
```

Now given an input and a class instantiation

```
inp = 0xDD120134A1A2B3E588
p1 = datastruct(inp)
print (f'Preamble: {p1.preamble}, Version: {p1.version}, Query No: {p1.queryType}')
```

Yields:

Preamble: Packet Preamble, Version: Version: 18, Query No: Query type accepted